# Automatically calls SQL Dump every page

Tags: cakephp, mysql

So after moving my cakephp app to production server, it seems that every page I am getting an SQL Dump.

The funny thing is, it appears in the source after the /html tag.

I figure it has something to do with the index.php file, but the only thing I have edited is the root directory.

Any ideas where I should start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set debug mode to 0 in /app/config/core.php

Comment: Fixed it immediately. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'll second alexdd55, in app/config/core.php, at about line 36, you will see:

```
    Configure::write('debug', 2);
```

Change the 2 (or 1 or whatever number might be there), to a 0.

Save that, and you should not see those generated any longer.

It is advised you should have your debug set to 2 if you are developing, so you can see what your SQL is doing..

Good luck!